# Entitiy FrameWorkCore One-to-Many Foreign key relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I was wondering about efcore's one-to-many relationship. What If I don't put in the inverse navigation property? Will it make any difference after I've already mapped the foreign key? Any advantage or disadvantage between both options?

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Blog")]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }     // **DO I NEED THIS BLOG OBJECT?**
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What If I don't put in the inverse navigation property? Will it make any difference after I've already mapped the foreign key? Any advantage or disadvantage between both options?

Reference: Relationships - [Single Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#single-navigation-property) EF Core documentation topic:

> Including just one navigation property (no inverse navigation, and no foreign key property) is enough to have a relationship defined by convention. You can also have a single navigation property and a foreign key property.

In fact EF Core fluent API and shadow properties allow defining relationship without any navigation or FK property. The main point is that none of them is mandatory. You could refer to the official documentations on [No Foreign Key Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#no-foreign-key-property) and [Without Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#without-navigation-property)

Of course the lack of a navigation property imposes some limitations on the type of LINQ queries you can create .